# Pandas dataframe to Snowflake with lowercase columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Goal is to write pandas dataframe to snowflake as-is with sqlachemy. Whether creating new table or adding rows to the existing one.

Problem is that when using snowflake sqlachemy engine, it converts all the column names and table name to uppercase.
The following code executes with no errors, but doesn't reserver object name cases either.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

snowflake_engine = create_engine({connection_settings_here})

df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1': 2, 'col2': 2}])

df.to_sql('test1',con=snowflake_engine, index=False)
```

**Is there a way to disable automatic uppercase in snowflake sqlalchemy engine or to force taking lowercase names?**

P.S. I have tried adding double quotes inside table definition:
`df.to_sql('\"test1\"',con=snowflake_engine, index=False)`
But then it creates triple quotes around it and fails:

```
CREATE TABLE """test1""" (
    col1 BIGINT, 
    col2 BIGINT
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are forcing column and table names to lowercase?  Snowflake converts them to uppercase, but you can still query them as lowercase.

Comment: @MikeWalton Yes, there are already lots of existing tables with lowercase column names and need to make work with it.

Comment: Ok - that's not a best practice for Snowflake, since it adds complexity to querying tables and columns when they need to be double-quoted.  I found this in the documentation, but not sure it helps you much: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#object-name-case-handling

Comment: Not sure if we have a good answer for this except perhaps if you could write a function as a wrapper.  As an extra side note, there is a little discussion here on some of the development choices: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/73

Comment: one of our tools expected lower case columns in all the results, and quoted all columns with lower case on it's sent SQL. so for that tool we turned on the session parameter QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE, but we also altered the tool to "toLower" all columns on return.. not sure if this is a path open to you.

Comment: Hi, there is an advocacy program that helps recognize Snowflake experts, you earn points from answers to questions, I can see some great answers in these comments, are any of them something to add as an answer? Check out https://community.snowflake.com/s/selectstar